# CSS Cursor Pointer

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui

I have weird issue. When I pass the value to cursor attribute as usual as string like

```
return (
  <Grid item>
    <Card 
      sx={{
        padding: "1rem",
        ":hover": {
          cursor: "pointer"
        }
      }}
    />
  </Grid>
)
```

it works correctly, but if I create constant with value of string pointer and then pass it to the cursor it doesn't work.

```
const cursorPointer = "pointer";
return (
  <Grid item>
    <Card 
      sx={{
        padding: "1rem",
        ":hover": {
          cursor: { cursorPointer }
        }
      }}
    />
  </Grid>
)
```

I am working with material ui, nextjs and typescript. Thanks.

Comment: did you mean to pass it without the object shorthand like: `cursor: cursorPointer`? If not, can you post up a running code example of what issue you are having, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber here is the first screenshot when i am passing value as a string and it's working https://ibb.co/g7sM3rh 
and here is the second screenshot when i am passing value as a constant and it doesn't work.  https://ibb.co/THKkPt6

Comment: @Nika What Zachary is saying is that you need to remove the curly brackets around `cursorPointer`. What you have now is the equivalent of `cursor: { cursorPointer: "pointer" }`.

Comment: Thanks guys i just needed to remove brackets. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't passing the value you think you are.

What you have in the second case actually looks like:

```
{
 ":hover": {
  cursor: { cursorPointer: "pointer" }
 }
}
```

Instead of

```
{
 ":hover": {
  cursor: "pointer" 
 }
}
```

You can use a variable with the following syntax

```
{
 ":hover": {
  cursor: cursorPointer 
 }
}
```